# StackTray: The Stack Overflow tray application

Tags: app, reputation, python, badges, linux

### Screenshot

[image]
Icon on left

[image]
Hover over icon

[image]
Context menu

[image]
Reputation Alerts

### About

This application sits in your system tray and periodically checks Stack Overflow for any new badges or reputation. It also displays your current reputation, allows for manual updates, and automatically opens a new tab in your browser and brings you to your user/reputation overview page.

### License

BSD License. http://creativecommons.org/licenses/BSD/

### Download

No direct download at the moment. Can be cloned via [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub).

### Platform

Was written and tested on [Debian Unstable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstable_%28Debian%29).

It should theoretically work anywhere Python 2.6 and [PyQt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt) 4 is installed (and working). I don't have the ability to test this on other operating systems.

### Contact

The easiest way would be to post in this thread or open an issue on GitHub.

### Code

This project was written in a few hours the night the Stack Overflow API was announced. There are probably plenty of bugs or bizarre things in the code. Be kind :-)

The code can be seen and cloned from here:
http://github.com/NickPresta/StackTray

Comment: So is this for KDE?

Comment: I suppose you could run this in a Gnome environment, but yeah, mostly for KDE.

Comment: Then I guess it goes hand-in-hand with my Gnome applet.

Comment: Indeed. You "inspired" me to write this.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that my work is inspirational!

Comment: Please relink the screenshots

Answer (score 2):

Has this been packaged anywhere?  I know from the information above it says get it from git, but just wondered if it has been updated?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would want this packaged? If you explain what would work well for you, I may be able to release an egg or something.

Answer (score 2):

A config thing in the GUI to set your ID would be nice.

And as far as packaging goes, why not upload it to KDE-Apps.org so we can grab it with Get Hot New Stuff on the Plasmoid picker?

I tried putting in my ID for ubuntu.stackexchange.com into lib/settings.py and s/stackoverflow/ubuntu.stackexchange/ on lib/stacktray.py but the text hover only ever says "Text" and I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/maco/code/StackTray/lib/systemtray.py", line 71, in run
> "You have %d reputation!" % self.rep, msecs=5000)
> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType

On the shell

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea. Add orange envelope-style updates and Windows compatibility and you've got a solid app. :)

Comment: Windows compatibility...?

Comment: That OS they call Microsoft Windows. ;)

Comment: @KTC: What's it like? Is it that new thing Google was talking about? Where can I see a demo?

Comment: Is there exists such windows ideas?