# Stack Overflow KDE Plasma widget

Tags: discussion, widget

Is a [Plasma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Plasma_Workspaces) widget being developed for Stack Overflow in [KDE 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Software_Compilation_4#Released_versions)?

I tried [StackTray](https://stackapps.com/questions/117/stacktray-the-stackoverflow-tray-application), but I'm thinking of something more complete to use as a widget on my desktop. I'd like to see this done, or take a try at it as soon as I have some time. I've developed [SuperKaramba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperKaramba) widgets before, so I'll check Plasma and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Please don't tag questions like this with `app`.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-desktop-notification-app ?

Comment: I had the same thought, and actually opened up a project in KDevelop, but I wouldn't count on me getting anything done any time soon. Have you considered hacking on StackTray? It looks promising, and I'm sure Nick would appreciate some help.