# Modifications to KDE StackTray

Tags: app

I modified the StackTray app so it now

- uses the Py-StackExchange library, to fix JSON parse errors, as version 0.8 of the StackOverflow API was phased out
- instead of displaying stuff like badges every N seconds, it displays a notification when there are changes to one's questions or reputation.
- fixed open popup clicking to display StackOverflow website, which would open *n* windows, where *n* is the number of refreshes. It should just open one window.

### screenshots

[image: startup message]

[image: reputation update message]

### todo

It needs some care from someone who has better knowledge of the Qt API. There's this message when one quits,

```
Application asked to unregister timer 0x40000003 which is not registered in this thread. Fix application.
```

and it'd be nicer if the KDE notification system were used.

### links

repository: https://github.com/gatoatigrado/StackTray

original: [StackTray: The Stack Overflow tray application](https://stackapps.com/questions/117/stacktray-the-stackoverflow-tray-application)

please email me (ntung@ntung.com) with any concerns if I don't respond to comments here.

Comment: Don't worry about the "Application asked to unregister timer 0x40000003 which is not registered in this thread. Fix application." error message - that's [a known bug with Qt](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com//browse/QTBUG-16558).